# MySQL query to make Friend of Friend network takes too long to run

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

I am trying to crete a Friend of Friend network, but the MySql query takes a very long time to run (my table has about 6 million users). I am new to SQL coding, so I am wondering if there is some way to accelerate my code.

I am trying to create a Friend of Friend network, using MySql on Python (SqlAlchemy). My table, named "projects" has two columns, Project_ID and Dev_ID. I define two developers working in the same project as "friends". Also, friend of friend is someone who is connected to a developer through a common friend, but not directly.

For example, consider two projects, with their members listed below:

`Project_ID      Dev_ID
    A               1
    A               2
    B               2
    B               3`

Then, I am looking to create a Friend of Friend table as below:

`dev_ID   project_ID   FoF   project_FoF
  1          A          3          B
  3          B          1          A`

This means, for dev_ID 1, {3} is a FoF since 1 and 3 are connected via {2} in atleast one project, but 1 and 3 do not work together. {2} does not have any FoF, so they are not listed in the output table.

The algorithm I tried to implement is, given 4 rows A, B, C, D from the table "projects":

I join A and B if they are from same project, I join B and C if they have the same developer, and I join C and D if they have the same project. I ensure, that A and B have different developers, B and C have different projects and C and D have different developers.

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.read_sql_query("""select DISTINCT A.project_id as project_1, D.project_id as project_FoF, A.dev_id as dev1, D.dev_id as FoF
                       from projects as A inner JOIN projects as B
                       on A.project_id=B.project_id
                       INNER JOIN projects as C
                       on B.dev_id=C.dev_id
                       INNER JOIN projects as D
                       on C.project_id=D.project_id
                       WHERE 
                       A.dev_id!=D.dev_id AND B.dev_id != D.dev_id AND A.dev_id != B.dev_id AND A.project_id!=D.project_id""", engine)
```

The code runs OK for small examples, (e.g., with a limit of 10,000), but with a very large database (about 6 Million rows), it runs for several hours before throwing an error, such as "InterfaceError: (mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query "

As suggested in comments, here is the output of the EXPLAIN query. Note "univ_dev_projects" is same as the table Projects in my example above.
[EXPLAIN query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oS3O.png)

And here is the output of the SHOW CREATE TABLE query, for the same table :

CREATE TABLE `univ_dev_projects` (\n `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n `dev_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n `project_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n PRIMARY KEY (`id`),\n KEY `project_id` (`project_id`),\n KEY `univ_dev_projects_dev_id_idx` (`dev_id`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=148532489 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN query` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the question as we need the informantion to answer performance related questions.. Without this question is simply unclear to be answerd.

Comment: Sounds like you be needing indexes on the columns used in the ON clause in the JOIN's that might be a reason for the `Lost connection to MySQL server during query ` error you basically *"DDoSed"* the server with that unindexed join query on millions off records which will result in a huge number of checks possibly high in the billions because of that MySQL killed the thread procesing the query to not bring down the complete server.... Keep in mind MySQL runs two  unindexed inner joins basically as four nested (for) [loops](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/nested-loop-joins.html)

Comment: *" but with a very large database (about 6 Million rows), it runs for several hours before throwing an error,"* Also you might want to prevent this in the future i would suggest setting [max_join_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_join_size) on runtime `SET max_join_size = 12000000` (as example) before running the query MySQL will directly give a error when it thinks it needs to scan more then 12000000  as you can catch statements where keys are not used properly and that would probably take a long time.

Comment: Hi @RaymondNijland, thanks a lot for taking the time to respond. I have added an Explain query output table with my question. Regarding adding an Index to columns, do you mean running a command like CREATE INDEX ID on projects(dev_ID)?  The reason I could not do this is because I do not have write access to the database in question.

Comment: Well the explain tells it needs to create a (possibly disk) based temporary table to process the query.. Based on the (estimated) record count i assume MySQL will create a disk based temporary table which is also bad for performance and also can be a reason for the error message you got..

Comment: But looking into the query after seeing the EXPLAIN and now with coffee and more focust there is no way it index/optimize this.. As the DISTINCT spans multiple tables (it would always require a temporary table/ possible a filesort aswell), the only way possible is making a [Materialized view/snapshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) but MySQl does not support that native so you will have to [simulate](http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/databases/creating-mysql-materialized-views/)

Comment: .. Still running the query to generate the "DISTINCT" table would be bad maybe do the processing in steps (divide and conquer algorithm/approach) or with pagination?

Comment: And also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as your query can be rewritten to give the same results but faster and `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the question would be still imporatant to know.

Comment: Hi @RaymondNijland, I have added the SHOW CREATE TABLE results. I am using a single table, called "projects" in the example code, so I am not sure what you mean by DISTINCT spanning multiple Tables. Thanks again, Swagatam

Comment: using a self join with aliases on the same table are still consider as separted ("tables") by the optimizer .. Also can you follow the instructions in the Minimal Reproducible Example link aswell as your current description and query does not provide clear enough infromation how the data looks like or how the results should be

Comment: @RaymondNijland sorry for my poor editing of the example tables, I have corrected them now. Hope my problem makes better sense now.